# Mass touch with dataloader to trigger an update from a workflow?

Tags: workflow, data-loader

I have a workflow that's updating a field on an object, but I don't want to have to manually touch each record to have them update. I saw mentioned that you can actually touch records with dataloader to force the updates. Can anyone shed any light on this for me please? Would you just update all the records to a new last activity date or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to actually modify any data on the record, simply perform a touch.

1. Query Data: Just grab the ID.

   `SELECT Id FROM SomeObject`
2. Update Data: Just map the ID from the previous export, and go.

EDIT: I should mention that you still need to make sure the workflow rule's evaluation criteria is met, or it won't have any effect.

Comment: Not even sure how to perform touch, is that a SQL command, that you would put in on the query?

Comment: SOQL can't perform DML. Instead, you use the data loader's "update" function.

Comment: Or you could be bold and do anonymous Apex in Developer Console if the # of records wasn't 'large', to wit: List<SomeObject> objList = [select id, ... from SomeObject]; update objList;